# Converting a nested JSON data into HTML table

Tags: java, json

I have a response JSON which I am trying to convert in to a html table. The response is something like below.

```
{
  "MySaves:a-us": {
    "addAnItemToMySaves": {
      "Overall": "fail",
      "sourceGuestLogin": "Pass",
      "guestLogin": "fail",
      "error": "headers cannot be null",
      "Source addAnItemToMySaves": "Pass",
      "addAnItemToMySaves": "fail"
    },
    "moveItemFromBagToMySaves": {
      "Overall": "fail",
      "sourceGuestLogin": "Pass",
      "guestLogin": "fail",
      "error": null,
      "addItemToCart": "fail",
      "moveItemFromBagToMySaves": "fail"
    },
    "currentMySavesList": {
      "Overall": "fail",
      "sourceGuestLogin": "Pass",
      "guestLogin": "fail",
      "error": "headers cannot be null",
      "addItemToCart": "fail",
      "moveItemFromBagToMySaves": "fail",
      "Source currentMySavesList": "Pass",
      "currentMySavesList": "fail"
    }
  },
  "Product:a-us": {
    "itemSizeGuide": {
      "Overall": "Pass",
      "Source itemSizeGuide": "Pass",
      "Target itemSizeGuide": "Pass"
    },
    "productItem": {
      "Overall": "Pass",
      "Source productItem": "Pass",
      "Target productItem": "Pass"
    },
    "productDetails": {
      "Overall": "Pass",
      "Source productDetails": "Pass",
      "Target productDetails": "Pass"
    },
    "inventoryByStore": {
      "Overall": "Pass",
      "Source inventoryByStore": "Pass",
      "Target inventoryByStore": "Pass"
    },
    "returnProductList": {
      "Overall": "Pass",
      "Source returnProductList": "Pass",
      "Target returnProductList": "Pass"
    }
  },
  "Share:a-us": {
    "getAShare": {
      "Overall": "fail",
      "sourceGuestLogin": "Pass",
      "guestLogin": "fail",
      "error": null,
      "addItemToCart": "fail",
      "getAShare": "fail"
    }
  }
}
```

I would like the root node in first column and the name the child node in second column, Overall status in third column and if overall is fail then error in fourth column. I am new to JSON so was wondering what would be the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var json={
  "MySaves:a-us": {
    "addAnItemToMySaves": {
      "Overall": "fail",
      "sourceGuestLogin": "Pass",
      "guestLogin": "fail",
      "error": "headers cannot be null",
      "Source addAnItemToMySaves": "Pass",
      "addAnItemToMySaves": "fail"
    },
    "moveItemFromBagToMySaves": {
      "Overall": "fail",
      "sourceGuestLogin": "Pass",
      "guestLogin": "fail",
      "error": null,
      "addItemToCart": "fail",
      "moveItemFromBagToMySaves": "fail"
    },
    "currentMySavesList": {
      "Overall": "fail",
      "sourceGuestLogin": "Pass",
      "guestLogin": "fail",
      "error": "headers cannot be null",
      "addItemToCart": "fail",
      "moveItemFromBagToMySaves": "fail",
      "Source currentMySavesList": "Pass",
      "currentMySavesList": "fail"
    }
  },
  "Product:a-us": {
    "itemSizeGuide": {
      "Overall": "Pass",
      "Source itemSizeGuide": "Pass",
      "Target itemSizeGuide": "Pass"
    },
    "productItem": {
      "Overall": "Pass",
      "Source productItem": "Pass",
      "Target productItem": "Pass"
    },
    "productDetails": {
      "Overall": "Pass",
      "Source productDetails": "Pass",
      "Target productDetails": "Pass"
    },
    "inventoryByStore": {
      "Overall": "Pass",
      "Source inventoryByStore": "Pass",
      "Target inventoryByStore": "Pass"
    },
    "returnProductList": {
      "Overall": "Pass",
      "Source returnProductList": "Pass",
      "Target returnProductList": "Pass"
    }
  },
  "Share:a-us": {
    "getAShare": {
      "Overall": "fail",
      "sourceGuestLogin": "Pass",
      "guestLogin": "fail",
      "error": null,
      "addItemToCart": "fail",
      "getAShare": "fail"
    }
  }
}

var tableRows="<table>";
Object.keys(json).forEach(function(k){
  
  var secondLevel=json[k];
  var first=true;
  var rowSpan=Object.keys(secondLevel).length;
  tableRows=tableRows+"<tr><td rowspan="+rowSpan+">"+k+"</td>";
  Object.keys(secondLevel).forEach(function(sk){
    if(!first){
      tableRows=tableRows+"<tr>";
    }
    tableRows=tableRows+"<td>"+sk+"</td>";
    var thirdLevel=json[k][sk];
    tableRows=tableRows+"<td>"+thirdLevel.Overall+"</td>";
    if(thirdLevel.Overall==="fail"){
      tableRows=tableRows+"<td>"+thirdLevel.error+"</td>";
    }else{
      tableRows=tableRows+"<td></td>";
    }
    tableRows=tableRows+"</tr>";
    first=false;
  });
  
});
tableRows=tableRows+"</table>";
document.getElementById("tableDiv").innerHTML=tableRows;
```

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="tableDiv"></div>
```